# Use of the word howbeit

Tags: phrases, sentence

I need to replace a sentence that I have in my corpus since I am using it twice in the same paragraph. My sentence starts with: `However, ...` and I want to use a similar expression in the similar style. Could i use the word `Howbeit, ...` instead (or Contrary, ...)?

Comment: I don't think you can use "Howbeit" this way. On the other hand, you could use...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can; all the dictionaries I've checked say so. However (sorry), it is archaic and so may not be the best choice. Alternatives:

-on the other hand (as the commenter says)

-yet

-and yet

-despite this fact

-even so

-but (no comma)

-this fact notwithstanding

Comment: Can i use:  This fact notwithstanding with comma?

Comment: Yes you can! Or you can say what the fact is: Notwithstanding the fact that . . . ,